# Android: Adding new layout-elemnts with ids/onclick through controller

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, parsing

Let's say i do have the following XML-File:

```
<LinearLayout > //Three Buttons
  <Button>Barcode</name>
  <Button>Ok</wert>
  <Button>Ok</wert>
</LinearLayout >
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<EditText/>
<EditText/>
```

Let's say by parsing it, i have found out that there are: 3 Buttons, 2 TextViews and 2 EditTexts.

**Questions**:

1. How do i add those **Elemnts** to another XML-File, with each Element having an ID, onClick-Event (both manually picked) ?
2. How to add, the corrensponding onClick Events to the Controller ?

**What i tried for 1st(after finding out a Element from corresponding XML-File):**

```
LinearLayout cst = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.idAttachmentLayout);//The id of the Page where the Elements should be added
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Hallo Welt");

cst.addView(btn);
```

Issue:[image: Error]

**UP**

Answer (score 0):

To access `R.id.idAttachmentLayout` you need first set / define the content where you are

in activity `onCreate`

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
```

in fragment `onCreateView`

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml, container);
```

then you can access your `R.id.idAttachmentLayout`
in fragment with `view.findViewById(R.id.idAttachmentLayout)`

You can add click event with `btn.setOnClickListener()`

The adding to view is right by you, you only need access view in correct time